# Unable to load sample React Native project on Android

Tags: react-native

I just started out with learning React Native and was following the official documentation. But 8081 is blocked by McAfee. So i started the JS server on 8069 port. But when i run the project on android using run-android command. I am getting the error in the image below. Can anyone help me out?

[error which pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozZRH.png)

Comment: How did you switch to port 8069? Did you also adjust the ADB port forwarding (`adb reverse`)?

Comment: Hello I did it my using a patch. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-port-patcher.

And then I did the ADB port forwarding too by adb reverse tcp:8069 tcp:8069. still no success.

Comment: I don't know what `react-native-port-patcher` does, but judging by the fact that the error message still mentions port 8081, there's a chance the code still expects to use it. Can you try running `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8069` ?

Comment: Hello. Error message doesnt mention 8081, it mentions 8069 and works on emulator too. I am having difficulty with device. I tried the command you said. Doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Open development menu select DevSettings and add Your development machine ip:port

Comment: Hello Mohamed. I already entered my ip:port and tried reloading the JS. As you can see in the screenshot, its calling the same URL. But still its not working out.

Comment: are You sure that the node packger is running

Comment: I opened the URL with the localhost:8069 and it shows React Packager Running

Comment: did You connect on real device or in simulator

Comment: Real device as well as emulator. I also did the adb reverse tcp:8069 tcp:8069

Comment: in real device needs to be connected via usb and simulator You need to run it first and ensure it is completely loaded

Comment: Can you please be a little more clear when you say USB and simulator? I mean can you tell me how to do it step by step?

Comment: You need to connect Your device with usb and enable it's developer mode

Comment: Hello Buddy. I am able to run on emulator now. But the error still persists on the device. Although the device and machine are connected to same wifi. I have a feeling my phone isnt able to resolve the my development machine's ip

Comment: You need to add numeric ip not localhost

Comment: so Your ip as You got from network configuration then : the port like 192.168.1.2:8069

Comment: did You enable usb debug mode

Comment: Hello Khalil. Yes i did both. If I didn't enable debug mode, my device wouldn't get recognized as a adb device at all